# How can I create an ec2 instance using vagrant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant

I want to create an ec2 machine using vagrant. But I am not able to do so

This is my vagrantfile.

```
require 'vagrant-aws'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"
  config.vm.box = 'dummy'
  config.vm.provider 'aws' do |aws, override|
    aws.keypair_name = 'test-sagar-gulabani-singapore'
    aws.instance_type = 't2.small'
    aws.region = 'ap-southeast-1'
    aws.ami = 'ami-0dad20bd1b9c8c004'
    #aws.security_groups = ['default']
    aws.tags = {
      'name'=>'sagar',
      'createdby'=>'sagar'
    }
  end
end
```

I am able to run this vagrant but it gets stuck on 
[image: Imgur]

What should I do ?

Comment: Was the instance created on console ? have you checked ?

Comment: Yes, it was created.

Comment: then the issue seems to be with the port number. try to telnet <ip> 22 from the host from which you are trying to run vagrant. Obvisously the instance should be in running state

Comment: Yes I am able to telnet